# How to delete rows from multiple tables using deleteRow() method

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset, delete-row

I've been working on the following code:

```
import java.sql.*;


public class deleteRowDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Connection con;
       Statement stmt;
       ResultSet rs;
       PreparedStatement ps;
       try    
       {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");
            stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs=stmt.executeQuery("select Mword, from Model,Stud where Mword=Sword");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                 ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into Compare (Cword) values (?)");
                 ps.setString(1,rs.getString(1));
                 ps.executeUpdate();  
                 rs.deleteRow();
            }
            con.close();   
       } catch(Exception e)
       {
          System.out.println(e);  
       }
   }
}
```

There are two tables Model and Stud. The two tables are being compared and all the words that are similar in both the tables are inserted in another table called Compare, at the same time i wish to delete the words from both the Stud and Model tables. The function deleteRow() works fine when the select statement has only one table , but how to work it out for complex select statements with multiple tables.

Comment: What is the primary key of Model and Stud?

Comment: There is no primary key... Do i need primary key?

Comment: Please do reply if you have any idea about this. I 've been working on my project for a long time and i am stuck here. Have Project ppt very soon :(

Comment: Yes, you need a primary key: "In the relational model, each table schema must identify a primary column used for identifying a row called the primary key." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). And what is exactly the problem? Do you get an error message or is it just that the delete is not done?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the row with a DELETE-statement. Exactly how this should be done depends upon your data model.

Instead of rs.deleteRow(); in the while loop, you could for instance do:

```
PreparedStatement deleteModel  = con.prepareStatement("DELETE Model WHERE Mword = ?"); // You might need to modify this query if Mword is not unique in Model.
deleteModel.setString(1, rs.getString(1));
deleteModel.executeUpdate();
//Do the same for Stud.
```